# window.applicationCache.swapCache() not updating new files

Tags: .htaccess, firefox, manifest

A bit confused. In creating a web app that will cache files, I use this chunk of code to recognize changes to the .manifest file. Works in Chrome, IE, and Safari:

```
    if('applicationCache' in window) {
      // Check if a new cache is available on page load.
      window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        window.applicationCache.addEventListener('updateready', function(e) {
          if (window.applicationCache.status == window.applicationCache.UPDATEREADY) {
            // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
            try { window.applicationCache.swapCache() } catch(err) { }
            // Swap it in and reload the page to get the new modified files.
            var reload = confirm('An update for the 360 Review is available. Apply update?');
            if (reload) window.location.reload();
          }
        }, false);
      }, false);
    }
```

In Firefox however, the confirm dialog box pops up when I change the .manifest file, but none of the pages I actually changed are updated. 
This is my .htaccess file:

```
    AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds" 
    Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate"
    <Files cache.manifest>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache"
    </Files>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
     ExpiresActive On
     ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
     </IfModule>
```

And of course the .manifest file (condensed):

```
    CACHE MANIFEST
    # v 4.8

    CACHE:
    css/pages.css
    index.html
```

I am currently running Firefox 28. Any help would be much appreciated.